# Как правильно сделать проверку обновлений версии приложения?

Tags: java, android

Есть такое приложение `GetTaxi` так вот когда есть доступное обновление, то при открытии приложения появляется pop-up и сообщает юзеру о доступном обновлении.

Я знаю что `play market` тоже предлагает обновления, но ведь это все регулируется настройками и можно отключить автоматическое обновление, нотификациию и все прочие.

Так вот я думаю сделать так, когда есть новый `versionCode` сохранять его значение на сервере, а приложение каждый раз при запуске отправляет запрос на сервер и проверяет совпадает ли цифра с цифрой на сервере, если нет то показываем `pop up` и прикрепляем ссылку

Вот такая идея)

Я не уверен что такое решение самое правильное поэтому интерисуюсь здесь

Спасибо

Comment: Да, нормальное обычное решение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть готовый библиотеки для такого(дофига). Просто поищи на гитхабе. Первая ссылка на гитхабе: https://github.com/rampo/UpdateChecker

Нужно еще подключить апаче в градл так как с 23 версией появились изменения

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
...
useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
...
}
```

Comment: да все работает очень хорошо, только в градл нужно добавить еще вот такое чтоб подключить апаче apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    ...
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
    ...
}

Answer (score 3):

Вполне нормальное решение. А всплывающий диалог сделать setCancelable(false) и по кнопке ок открывать плэй маркет. Только нужно убедиться, что плэймаркет уже опубликовал версию, иначе казус выйдет =)

Comment: я просто думал еще может как то можно с сервера проверять обновление на плее и если есть доступное то кидать нотификацию... Но это наверное более ресурсоемко...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Пару лет назад я искал какое-нибудь апи к плэй маркету, так и не нашел ничего работающего. От самого гугла не было.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с проверкой новой версии приложения со своего сервера является довольно гибким, но в самом простом случае (когда версия приложения не зависит от устройства) наиболее рациональным решением я считаю проверку версии именно из Google Play.

Получить текущую версию приложения из Google Play можно, например, так:

```
private class GetNewVersionCodeTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        String newVersion;
        try {
            newVersion = Jsoup.connect("link_to_your_app_in_google_play")
                    .timeout(30*1000)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36")
                    .referrer("https://www.google.ru")
                    .get()
                    .select("div[itemprop=softwareVersion]")
                    .get(0)
                    .text();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }

        return newVersion;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String newVersion) {
        super.onPostExecute(newVersion);

        if (newVersion != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), newVersion, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            // some actions
        }
    }
}
```

Здесь для простоты реализована связка `AsyncTask` + `Jsoup`, но, разумеется, Вы можете воспользоваться средствами, которые наиболее привычны для Вас.